# No depth buffer on framebuffer when using shadow mapping

Tags: opengl-es, shadow

I have got shadow mapping working nice on android but there is a problem - shadows 'leak'. So imagine a cylinder imbedded in the floor of a terrain with some portion under that terrain. The portion above creates a nice shadow opposite to the light source but the potion under the terrain casts a shadow forwards - towards the light. Its as if there is no depth buffer.
Here is my frambuffer code (where i think the problem is).

```
MyGLRenderer.shadowsize=4096;

    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, temp2qshadow, 0);
    LoadIntroPics.fboTexqshadow = temp2qshadow[0];
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboTexqshadow);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, MyGLRenderer.shadowsize, MyGLRenderer.shadowsize/2, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, tempqshadow, 0);
    MyGLRenderer.fboIdshadow = tempqshadow[0];
    GLES20.glGenRenderbuffers(1, temp3qshadow, 0);
    LoadIntroPics.renderBufferIdqshadow = temp3qshadow[0];
    GLES20.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBufferIdqshadow);
    GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, MyGLRenderer.shadowsize, MyGLRenderer.shadowsize/2); 
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, MyGLRenderer.fboIdshadow);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, LoadIntroPics.fboTexqshadow);

    GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER,LoadIntroPics.renderBufferIdqshadow); 

    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, LoadIntroPics.fboTexqshadow, 0);
```

And this is the shadow map code....

```
protected String getVertexShaderShadow()//this needs a model view projection matrix
{
    final String vertexShader =
    "precision highp float;       \n"   
    +"attribute vec4 a_Position;  \n"
    +"uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;   \n"
    //+"uniform mat4 u_ShadowMatrix;   \n"
    +"attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate; \n"
    +"varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;     \n"
    +"varying vec4 v_v4TexCoord;   \n"

    +"void main()                   \n" 

    +"{                             \n"
    +"v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;       \n"
    +"gl_Position =u_MVPMatrix * a_Position;   \n"
    +"v_v4TexCoord = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position;  \n"
    +"}                                       \n";      
    return vertexShader;
}

protected void getFragmentShaderShadow()
{
    final String fragmentShader =
    "precision highp float;       \n"
    +"uniform sampler2D u_Texture; \n"  
    +"uniform int decal;  \n"
    +"varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;     \n"
    +"varying vec4 v_v4TexCoord;   \n"
    +"void main()                   \n"     
    +"{                \n"

    +"vec4 col=texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate); \n"
    +"if(decal==1){if(col.r<=0.25 && col.g<=0.25 && col.b<=0.25)discard;} \n"
    +"if(decal==2){if(col.r<=0.05 && col.g<=0.05 && col.b<=0.05)discard;} \n"


    /* Generate shadow map - write fragment depth. */
    +"float value = 10.0 - v_v4TexCoord.z;  \n"
    +"float v = floor(value);  \n"
    +"float f = value - v;  \n"
    +"float vn = v * 0.1;  \n"
    +"gl_FragColor = vec4(vn, f, 0.0, 1.0);  \n"


    //+"gl_FragColor=vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);  \n"
    +"}                                                                     \n";    
    fragmentShaderHandle =compileShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);     
    MyGLRenderer.mPerVertexProgramHandleShadow = createAndLinkProgram(MyGLRenderer.vertexShaderHandleShadow, fragmentShaderHandle, 
        new String[] {"a_Position",  "a_Color", "a_Normal", "a_TexCoordinate"});
}
```

And ideas? Thanks

Here is a snapshot.
[image]

Comment: Done that, thanks for taking the time to read my question, I'm struggling with this! You can see the problem in the picture and also a lot of self shadowing on the peaks of the pink structures. The VERY distant ones look ok because I am blending out shadows with distance.

Comment: Yes its a pipe, FRONT face culling is enabled. If I dont do that it looks even worse.

Comment: but its casting the shadow forwards - towards the light, and its cast from under the ground You can see the shadow correctly to the left (across the floor and up the pink wall) but also incorrectly to the right. The light (and shadow camera) is up and to the right looking down and to the left.

Comment: I dont have backface culling enabled - only fronfaces are culled. Every object in my shadow map casts a shadow on everything else, regardless of depth. so very distant objects are casting shadows on things in the foreground.